# Length of a list inside a list and return boolean

Tags: haskell

I am fairly new to Haskell and I am trying to find the length of a list inside a list and return true if it is more than 3 and vise versa.
For example:

```
[[Bool]] -> Bool
xs = length xs >= 3
```

This returns true if the outer list is equal or over 3, but I want to check if the inner lists have the same argument.
Also, I know that map length produces a list of the length of the 2nd list.

```
[[T,F,T],[F,F,T],[F,F]] -- output : False
[[T,F,T],[F,F,T],[T,F,F]] -- output : True
```

This is what I am expecting to find.

I hope the explanation of my problem is clear, thanks.

Comment: There are multiple lists inside the outer one. It isn't clear which one you want to check the length of.

Comment: I want to check if the lists inside the big one have a length (>=) to 3

Comment: I corrected the question to be more clear

Comment: So, are you trying to find out if the length of inner lists are all greater than or equal to 3?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you written other functions that work on lists?  This will help us give an answer that uses things you already know.

Comment: `and` and `or` are your friends in this quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution using the [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:14) function:

```
check :: [[Bool]] -> Bool
check = all ((>=3) . length)
```

The `all` function will return `True` when every element satisfies a predicate; in this case the predicate `(>=3) . length` evaluates to `True` when a list's length is greater than or equal to three. So, if `all` the inner lists have a length greater than or equal to three, then `check` evaluates to `True`.

Using the code you've provided and avoiding point-free style, maybe this will help piece together the above solution:

```
lengthGreaterEqualThree :: [Bool] -> Bool
lengthGreaterEqualThree xs = length xs >= 3

check' :: [[Bool]] -> Bool
check' listOfLists = all lengthGreaterEqualThree listOfLists
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's four solutions:

#### Explicit recursion

```
allLongerThanThree :: [[a]] -> Bool
allLongerThanThree []     = True
allLongerThanThree (x:xs) = (length x) >= 3 && allLongerThanThree xs
```

#### Map and `and`

```
allLongerThanThree :: [[a]] -> Bool
allLongerThanThree = and . fmap ((>=3) . length)
```

#### Folding

```
allLongerThanThree :: [[a]] -> Bool
allLongerThanThree = (foldr ((&&) . (>=3) . length) True)
```

#### Using `all`

```
allLongerThanThree :: [[a]] -> Bool
allLongerThanThree = all ((>=3) . length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the sublists have length 3 or greater, then the list of sublists *shorter* than 3 should be empty:

```
hasShortLists :: [[a]] -> Bool  -- The contents of the inner lists doesn't matter
hasShortLists = null . filter ((<3) . length)
```

(This is basically deconstructing `all` a notch; it's also equivalent to `not . any ((< 3) . length)`.)